# Object.fromEntries in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to declare type `ObjectFromEntries` which behaves like return type of `Object.fromEntries` function. So:

```
type ObjectFromEntries<Entries extends [keyof any, any][]> = { [key in Entries[number][0]]: ___ };

declare var z: ObjectFromEntries<[["a", number], ["b", string], ["c", Date]]>
z.a // expected: number
z.b // expected: string
z.c // expected: Date
```

But I don't know what to place instead of `___`.

If I try `key extends Entries[infer I][0] ? Entries[I][1] : never` I get an error

> Type 'I' cannot be used to index type 'Entries'.(2536)
>   Type '0' cannot be used to index type 'Entries[I]'.(2536)

If I try `Entries[number][1]` I get type `string | number | Date` for every property and that's logical.

How can I sync up `key` with index to get a proper type?

Comment: Honestly it has never ever occurred to me to try to `infer` inside a lookup type like `X extends T[infer K] ? K : never`.  I'm kind of surprised there's an error message but I'm not surprised it doesn't work, because `K` will probably be inferred as `keyof T`.

Comment: @jcalz, seems like it's just an unsupported syntax, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it like this:

```
type ObjectFromEntries<Entries extends [keyof any, any][]> = {
    [K in Entries[number][0]]: Extract<Entries[number], [K, any]>[1]
} 

declare var z: ObjectFromEntries<[["a", number], ["b", string], ["c", Date]]>
z.a.toFixed();
z.b.toUpperCase();
z.c.getFullYear();
```

Note that since you only ever consult `Entries[number]` I'd probably write it like this instead:

```
type ObjectFromEntrySet<E extends [keyof any, any]> = {
    [K in E[0]]: Extract<E, [K, any]>[1]
}

declare var y: ObjectFromEntrySet<["a", number] | ["b", string] | ["c", Date]>
y.a.toFixed();
y.b.toUpperCase();
y.c.getFullYear();
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwgY2AMQE4HsC2BRAO2AwEsIBnAHkOLPKggA9gICATegbQGsIQsAZlACGBEABoRYgLqdpAPigBeKAG8AUFC1ROAaSgkCUGqQqcCAVxxwIGWQAZp0gFzHmGYampFT5c1Zs7ST1JURAFTgBGaXUAX011NhQAG2EMaAA3NKgAL1d4JFRMXBM6Sk5OACJhSslLa1tpYMq4WqhyWgIAcyadSuQ2gBFhFid5dRyAOmFJ4Cw0EkYINgAKAEoAbgnJuFmsAFUwSAwAYWFyCHWtqeRJroh0C2TkgE0INKv1dVBIWEQUdDYfA+EAAZQe1AYzFYHB0vH4QjCoRkihUGm0On0hmMnEcLjcxE8wGowV0yPC8iiMXiiRSaUy2RA+X+RSBJjBEKqNTqAUaUAAPn1WpIOqRutIBX0BpJhqNxiBpnsFktVpt1ArdnNDsczhdPgrbvdHs83h9NkA)

Answer (score -4):

You can get this by adding `"lib": ["ES2019"]` to `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["ES2019"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it produces the correct type? I tried in [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/MYewdgzgLgBAHjAvDA8gIwFYFNhQHQBmATiALYCiYURAllhABQDaTARAIasA0MAjALo82AR1HcYrYQHcsrfvxjsIMUJCgBKAFBA) and see only 2 overloads: `fromEntries(entries: Iterable<readonly any[]>): any` and `fromEntries(entries: Iterable<readonly [string | number | symbol, any]>): { [k: string]: any; }`. For the code `const x = Object.fromEntries([["a", 1], ["qqq", "qwe"]] as const)` I get `any`, not `{ a: 1, qqq: "qwe" }`.