# Restrain inferred type of Object.fromEntries

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, typescript-typings

The inferred return type of the following function is `{[k: string]: number}`:

```
export const dateParts = (
  date: Date,
  timeZone?: string
) => {
  const options = {
    day: "numeric",
    month: "numeric",
    timeZone,
    year: "numeric",
  } as const;
  const formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en", options);
  const parts = formatter.formatToParts(date);
  return Object.fromEntries(
    parts
      .filter(({ type }) => ["year", "month", "day"].includes(type))
      .map(({ type, value }) => [type, Number(value)])
  );
};
```

But for the keys of the returned object the only posible options are `year`, `month`, and `day`.

Is there a way to restrain the keys of the returned object to be only those?

I tried explicitly adding the return type as `{'year': number, 'month': number, 'day': number}` or `Record<'year' | 'month' | 'day', number>`:

```
export const dateParts = (
  date: Date,
  timeZone?: string
): { year: number; month: number; day: number } => {
```

But then it conflicts with what `Object.fromEntries` is returning:

```
Type '{ [k: string]: number; }' is missing the following properties from type '{ year: number; month: number; day: number; }': 'year', 'month', 'day' ts(2739)
```

I haven't been able to figure out how to modify the return type of `Object.fromEntries` so it matches `{'year': number, 'month': number, 'day': number}` instead of `{[k: string]: number}`.

Comment: "*It conflicts with what Object.fromEntries*" - can you post the type error that you get when you use `Object.fromEntries(…) as …` with your preferred return type?

Comment: @Bergi casting the returned type with `as` works... but, can we make it infer the correct type instead of casting it?

Comment: I doubt it. Generic `Object` builtins are typed pretty badly in Typescript. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/59996713/1048572, https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31393 and especially https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35745

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the compiler cannot follow your logic at the type-level strongly enough to give you the types you're looking for.  At each step along the way: `filter()`, `map()`, and `Object.fromEntries()`, the compiler produces a correct but too-wide-to-be-useful type.

Ultimately you're going to want to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) like this:

```
  return Object.fromEntries(
    parts
      .filter(({ type }) => ["year", "month", "day"].includes(type))
      .map(({ type, value }) => [type, Number(value)])
  ) as Record<'year' | 'month' | 'day', number>;
```

This is a reasonable approach for situations, like this one, where you know more than the compiler about the type of a value.

---

The alternative is to provide your own more specific typings for/to `filter()`, `map()`, and `Object.fromEntries()`, which are likely to be useful only for this specific line of code, and have their own caveats.

For example, the compiler does not realize that `({type} => ["year", "month", "day"].includes(type))` acts as a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) on its input.  Type guard functions are not inferred automatically; you would have to annotate it yourself as a [user-defined type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates), like this:

```
const filteredParts = parts
  .filter((part): part is { type: "year" | "month" | "day", value: string } =>
    ["year", "month", "day"].includes(part.type))
/* const filteredParts: {
type: "year" | "month" | "day";
value: string;
}[] */
```

Now the output of `filter()` will be narrow enough.  The caveat here is that the compiler just believes you that a user-defined type guard does what it says it's doing, so it's like a type assertion.  Had you written `["foo", "bar", "baz"].includes(part.type)`, instead, the compiler wouldn't notice or warn you.

Then, when you return an array literal inside `map()` like `[key, val]`, the compiler will widen it to an unordered array type like `Array<typeof key | typeof val>`, whereas you specifically need a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) like `[typeof key, typeof val]`.  So you'll need to change that behavior, possibly by using a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```
const mappedParts = filteredParts.map(
  ({ type, value }) => [type, Number(value)] as const
);
// const mappedParts: (readonly ["year" | "month" | "day", number])[]
```

Great, now you have something to pass to `Object.fromEntries()`.  Unfortunately, the [TypeScript standard library's type definitions for `Object.fromEntries()`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/38da7c600c83e7b31193a62495239a0fe478cb67/lib/lib.es2019.object.d.ts#L23-L35) just returns either `any`, or something with a `string` [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types).

If you want, you could [merge in](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) your own type signature that returns a [key-remapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#key-remapping-in-mapped-types) which more accurately represents things (and it will have to be a [global augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation) if you are using modules), like this:

```
interface ObjectConstructor {
  fromEntries<T extends readonly [PropertyKey, any]>(
    entries: Iterable<T>
  ): { [K in T as T[0]]: T[1] };
}
```

And then, finally, your return value will be strongly typed the way you want:

```
const ret = Object.fromEntries(mappedParts);
/* const ret: {
  year: number;
  month: number;
  day: number;
} */
```

Is it worth all that?  I doubt it.  It's up to you though.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBBKUICcAuSDeAsAFBJLwD2wUuAJiNhAAog5RIC8SAFMaaXQwBcSACL0IAGl59sAS0gAtShAD8w6plnAA5tICUHAHz5ppClVzkYcym06ESffiACewgETAArpE3x3Uo5OYJTYABYe3r6y-oFOpHKKynHxLhAskT5YMQGmSAC+SCBs5tQA3HmluABm5Jhg9AyYHEjAEADuSACSwNgANgB0YgwAKvIQAGJ1Ddhc7hDAAUhWNlR6FUFktrhwrC219Y1YAwczI+TMrFwCEOt5mBDYXpjASADyAEYAVhDw2CeYchgACivU00B4m1Iu2wUDyThOsj6TS4XDwSGwLhgyHyBnYxgA2u40iwlu4Qr0wmS6C53ABdAZaeB9Lw0CGY7F6PTwvgDBowVHojmSJAANxALJxeMJwokSAAcj4PlguOLJXo6dzNgZikgAEq-Oo0AA8AHISZhTUgAD5IU0U8JW22mmmmuVRZWYQwbUj5DbSUrkPoQAZ9cjaa7iS6wrhtTrDCBcLl80JhAbYcgTWQADwgNC4ACYuRt8sRiFomtUEMhPj8-gBhbaYLx-OomRzVQEgsGyaDGkZICDZhjAGhsB4gGiUPouJAExiA7E4FwAaQgLjlIGALjphkhTgW2HBUGEXSaIA+wf7hn0wnRBJXSC0SAHupGBIADHS6cJ3wBGOkChLMsiFASBYGrF9MBcc5G2AUUmQgEYwggRswBgJEsHbMxtiQG5ozsbg8huYQExSBJxiUNo1CQDQtF0RxpWwvgqmWaxZFsFoHHiPDXEyaJYh5B0IiQTwsj8XIoQxSjkh5C1+OyQTNkKXUqh9FjcNOI5mk4ONul6QYEzGSApkOWZ5kWOUVg4tZ1JwiwkBhQitOwJoTmmehzgIyMGDuIhKk0pEmjzAiWicnlEWRFUuBhPRhBhJ82CFLEIA8C13BtUThIy213BpJY1S8VLaKPeiCiMHlSCJdK5XJVNqVcelGWAZlWQhGF0xSrk8gAegAKi2BzqiCrAQpYWE7zyYU0vSTAcqy+rMryxq7LFCUivUUqdFW-ICUAvqepApxWP5bEaFCzhhqih5zvGqA+RAAU0QxFK5UKqUjDnWUFSVFV3o1IoSm2PynB6nrBuoJBTrG1hhC4Ccp2AGc52JWb5rqyl0fy91fswTU9qOjSHIeXBOFrX5-k7IFQVKiFodu1gQb4fqIdwEnJs2eTWlx1bhOED0sFWml+Z5vJCgO+5HmeV4SfUv1CcDYNQ3DHymDu2MOlEcQkz0FNKXTTMczzQti2IfIgA)